# TypeError: Password must be a string or bytes, got BoundField

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a login page. There I want to receive json format at backend, with fields username and password in string format. But when I try to authenticate username and password (in views.py). I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Password must be a string or bytes, got BoundField.
```

***views.py***

```
from .serializers import event_serializer, student_serializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError

@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = student_login_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("serializer is valid")
            username_pwd = serializer
            username = username_pwd["username"]
            password = username_pwd["password"]
            student = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if student is not None:
                login(request, student)
                events = Event.objects.all()
                serializer = event_serializer(events, many=True)
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    elif request.method == "GET":
        users = Student.objects.all()
        serializer = student_serializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

***serializers.py***

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Student, Club, member_request, Event, Comment
from django import forms

class student_login_serializer(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    fields = ['username', 'password']
```

***models.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class Student(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Please feel free to ask me for more details regarding this problem and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's true because your serializer return `html` element.
So, `authenticate` function was not work properly.

In Your case **serializer** return this:

```
> <tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input
> type="text" name="username" value="pradip" placeholder="Username"
> required id="id_username"></td></tr> <tr><th><label
> for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td><input type="text"
> name="password" value="admin123@" placeholder="Password" required
> id="id_password"></td></tr>
```

**Try this:**

```
    @api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
    def login_view(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            serializer = student_login_serializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                print("serializer is valid")
                student = authenticate(username=request.data.get('username'),password=request.data.get('password'))
                if student is not None:
                    login(request, student)
                    events = Event.objects.all()
                    serializer = event_serializer(events, many=True)
                    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
                else:
                    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif request.method == "GET":
            users = Student.objects.all()
            serializer = student_serializer(users, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```